# Talend job as a webservice in cloud

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jar, talend

I have built a few Talend job using cloud application's API and I was wondering to build it as a webservice to put in the cloud like for example in AWS.

For standard Java application I'm used to have the capability to build a .war and deploy it inside a Tomcat for example. But I can't find any proper documentation to build a talend Job as a webservice in 7.x (and AWS if someone has any clue what to do precisly !).

Thanks

Comment: I can't see any problem. Maybe this document can be useful https://devops4solutions.com/installation-of-tomcat-on-aws-ec2-linux-integration-with-jenkins/

Comment: Yeah but this is for .war application. Talend only build .jar
I found this to build a .war https://help.talend.com/r/sXztzFOIighK6zMvQQBj1w/8WEuVasHVS4GI8NKjLep3Q but I don't have this option in my Talend Open Studio

Comment: Maybe you you can create a war file with a single endpoint that runs your jar

Comment: That could be indeed a very easy solution

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use talend open studio for ESB and use components like tRESTRequest and tRESTResponse as starting and ending component of your service. This will allow you to build them as kar file and deploy them in  container apache Karaf.